# UICollectionViewcell calling functions over and over

Tags: swift

I have go this uicollectionviewcell

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! PostCell
    if let CurrentPost = posts[indexPath.row] as? Post{
        //determine which constraint to call
        if(CurrentPost.PostText != nil){
            if(CurrentPost.PostImage != nil){
                cell.postImage.image = CurrentPost.PostImage
                cell.cellConstraintsWithImageWithText()
            }else{
                cell.postImage.image = nil
                cell.cellConstraintsWithoutImageWithText()
            }
        }else{
            cell.postImage.image = CurrentPost.PostImage
            cell.cellConstraintsWithImageWithoutText()
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

My goal is to determine which function to goal based on absence or presence of image and text.Now the problem is all this functions get called because some cells do have images `cellConstraintsWithImageWithText` is being called,others don't have them so `cellConstraintsWithoutImageWithText` is being called.How can i call a single function for a single cell rather than all cells?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because cells are being reused. The easiest way to handle this is to store index paths of cells with text in your view controller. When cell is dequeued just check if index path is present in stored array and layout accordingly.

In your `ViewController`

```
var cellsWithText: [IndexPath] = []
```

In `cellForItemAt indexPath`

```
...
cell.postImage.image = nil
cell.cellConstraintsWithoutImageWithText()
if !cellsWithText.contains(indexPath) {
    cellsWithText.append(indexPath)
}
...
```

Now at the beginning at `cellForItemAt indexPath`

```
if let CurrentPost = posts[indexPath.row] as? Post {
    if cellsWithText.contains(indexPath) {
    // layout for text
    } else {
    // layout for image
    }
```

I also noticed that your'e using `posts[indexPath.row]` but your using the collectionView, that doesn't have rows and has `item` instead. That also might be the issue.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what i'm doing?

Comment: @sakoaskoasko you're storing posts, and I offer to store index paths. On initial dequeue you just add index path of the cell to array if it has text. When the collection view will deque this cell again it should check if index path of this cell is present in the array. If so it's a text layout if not image.

Comment: @sakoaskoaso hey, I updated the answer with some code, and also notice my remark about indexPath.row